# Redundant values while fetching distinct values from column after joins

Tags: sql, postgresql

While I was trying to fetch unique email ids from my postgres database, I am still getting redundant values. The query is as follows :

```
select distinct(t2.email_id), user_id, registration_date, 
  last_login, status, count_uo  
from (
  select t1.* 
  from (
    select distinct(u.email_id), u.user_id, 
      u.registration_date, u.last_login, 
      u.status, count(distinct(uo.id)) as count_uo 
    from users u 
    join user_offers uo on u.user_id = uo.user_id 
      and u.email_id != ''  
      and uo.offer_id in ('13', '9', 18, 7, 19, 25) 
    join user_utils uu on u.user_id = uu.user_id 
      and uu.carrier ~* 'Airtel' 
      or  uu.carrier ~* 'Jio' 
      or  uu.carrier ~* 'Idea' 
      or  uu.carrier ~* '!dea' 
    where u.registration_date::date between date'2016-08-04' and date'2017-09-28' 
      and u.last_login::date between date'2017-06-01' and date'2017-09-29' 
      and u.gender = 'm' 
      and u.status = 'sms-verified' 
      and u.email_verification_status = 'UN-VERIFIED' 
      and u.email_id != '' group by u.user_id
    ) as t1 
  where t1.count_uo >1 and t1.count_uo < 100
) t2;
```

I get the output as follows, even after applying distinct twice.

```
email_id       | user_id |     registration_date      |         last_login         |    status    | count_uo 
---------------+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------+--------------+----------
 abc@gmail.com |     509 | 2017-07-26 16:59:50.608219 | 2017-07-26 17:56:54.88664  | sms-verified |        3
 def@gmail.com |     518 | 2017-08-18 19:26:45.217283 | 2017-08-22 15:38:01.591841 | sms-verified |        3
 abc@gmail.com |     512 | 2017-08-17 12:01:00.003048 | 2017-08-21 17:52:56.303841 | sms-verified |        3
```

Since I'm weak in SQL, any help will be appreciated very much.

Comment: Your results are unique.  It is unclear what you want to do.  You should also put some effort into formatting the query.

Comment: I want unique email ids from the table

Comment: You are probably getting duplicate emaile because there is probably multiple `user offers` for a given user. If you want just unique email ids and that it I can write an answer for that.

Comment: Yes there are multiple values for user offers in table user_offers and also in table user_utils for a given user. It would be great if you can answer that. Since I'm also willing to learn SQL, it would be nice if you could also explain the way to proceed with these type of queries.

Comment: So for an email that two users share (`abc@gmail.com` for users 509 and 512 in your example), which user do you want to show?

Comment: Any of them will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Postgres, you can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (t2.email_id) t2.email_id, user_id,
       registration_date, last_login, status, count_uo  
from ( . . . ) t2
order by t2.email_id;
```

You can add a second key to the `order by` to get a particular row (say the most recent login by using `order by t2.email_id, last_login desc`).

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error for this. See the screenshot at  [syntax error screenshot](https://s1.postimg.org/8ayoqw0qmn/sql_Error.png)

Comment: After taking your hint and reading about distinct on, it worked. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You have two users (rows) with 'abc@gmail.com' as *email_id*: Notice that they have **distinct** value in *user_id* column (509 and 512).

As @GordonLinoff said, you can hide one of that results by using `DISTINCT ON` clause. But I figure out that it's not what you want...

I imagine it's more likely you inserted some test data and duplicated 'abc@gmail.com' in it.

This also point out (I think) a mistake in your model definition. (missing *UNIQUE* constraints over both *email_id* and *user_id* columns in your *users* table to avoid it could happen again I mean).

Comment: Actually a user can have multiple email_ids as per the schema, the only thing that distinguishes the the phone number and device id, since it is an app based backend. 
Actually I just want to fetch unique email_ids from the database according to the applied filters. It would be great if you can help me out with that

Comment: Ok. I just were speculating about requiremente that, in fact, I did'nt know. But, as @GordonLinof already explained, if you want to obtain unique *email_id*'s, then you should not to include *user_id* or, at least, be aware that you will obtain random (or already selected by *order by* clause) one. On the other hand, there is the option to use an aggregate function to get a list (array, string…) of **all** usei_id regarding to the same *email_id*.

Comment: I just figured out a working solution (may not be a good one). You can find it at https://pastebin.com/6mMK8ueY . It would be great if you can review the solution and help me optimise it. Moreover, I also want to show registration date, but since it is an array, it's quite tough. It will be good, if you can help me with that.